# Representation of reductive Lie algebras

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{L}$ be a reductive Lie algebra. Suppose that $\mathfrak{L}$ is a direct sum of $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{h}$ as Lie algebras where $\mathfrak{g}$ is a semisimple Lie algebra and $\mathfrak{h}$ is its center. Is every representation of $\mathfrak{L}$ a tensor product of a representation of $\mathfrak{g}$ and a representation of $\mathfrak{h}$?

Comment: Context? What have you tried? Standard examples like $\mathfrak{gl}_n$?

Comment: Let $\mathfrak g = \mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C)$ and $\mathfrak h = \mathbb C$ (the $1$-dimensional abelian Lie algebra). Let $W_1$ be the defining $2$-dimensional rep of $\mathfrak g$, viewed as $\mathfrak L$-rep with $\mathfrak h$ acting via $0$, and $W_2$ be the $1$-dimensional identity rep of $\mathfrak h$, viewed as $\mathfrak L$-rep with $\mathfrak g$ acting via $0$. Let $V = W_1 \oplus W_2$. I do not see a way to write $V$ as a tensor product of a $\mathfrak g$- and an $\mathfrak h$-representation (but I could be wrong).

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Thanks. When I read the theorem a Lie superalgebra is a classical Lie superalgebra  if and only if its even is a reductive Lie algebra. In its proof，they seem use this result，so I raise this question.

Comment: I don't know about the specific case of reductive Lie algebras, but normally when this kind of result is stated, we need the representation to be irreducible. Is it true that every _irreducible_ representation of $\mathfrak{L}$ is a tensor product? (I think so: since $\mathfrak{h}$ is abelian, the whole irreducible representation must be concentrated in a single $\mathfrak{h}$-weight, and so this weight can be factored out into a tensor product with a 1-dimensional representation).